# show groupboxes depending on selection in listbox access database vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, listbox, visual-studio-2019

I have an access databasetable with addresses and a table with addresstypes.
When i add a new relation there's different groupboxes with additional information that should be displayed according to the addresstype.
For example: a patient has only basic address info.
A doctor needs a reference number too, so if i click on relation type "doctor" the address groupbox should appear but also the groupbox with doctor reference textbox.
An instance should also get the instance groupbox + address groupbox etc etc.
Addresses can also be "multiple types" so if an address is A: a doctor, and B an instance, both boxes should appear.
My current code looks like this:

```
Public Class NewRelationForm

        'groupboxen disablen on load
        Me.grpKiesUwRelatietype.Visible = True
        Me.grpBasisData.Visible = False
        Me.grpDataBI.Visible = False
        Me.grpFoto_Nota.Visible = False
        Me.grpHuisartsData.Visible = False
        Me.grpPartijData.Visible = False
        Me.grpVerwijzerdata.Visible = False

    End Sub

    'KNOPPEN en Functies!
    Private Sub NewRelationForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
               Me.Tbl_TypeTableAdapter1.Fill(Me.PatientenDatabaseDataSetX1.tbl_Type)
Me.Tbl_OnderzoeksTypesTableAdapter.Fill(Me.PatientenDatabaseDataSetX1.tbl_OnderzoeksTypes)
Me.Tbl_RelatiesTableAdapter.Fill(Me.PatientenDatabaseDataSetX.tbl_Relaties)
    End Sub
    Private Sub btnAddRelation_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddRelation.Click
        FormMakeRelationType.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub lboxRelatieTypes_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lboxRelatieTypes.SelectedIndexChanged

    End Sub

    'Private Sub lboxRelatieTypes_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lboxRelatieTypes.SelectedIndexChanged
    ''If ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
    ''    grpBasisData.Visible = True
    ''    grpFoto_Nota.Visible = True
    ''    grpFoto_Nota.Location = New Point(720, 120)
    ''End If
    'End Sub

End Class
```

I could really use a pointer in how to do this, i've tried if else, i've tried select case, but i can't find "the right way".
I'm a beginner
edit1: This is a pic from the winform: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYexM.jpg
and this is the access db (names in the db are changed for privacy purposes
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/4gudk8lwxtjahiq/AACz69ocFWIlU7hiTlQxbviLa?dl=0

Comment: @lzzy, can you provide the table in the access database and the image you design in the winform?  It can make your problem more clear.

Comment: @JackJJun-MSFT: I added your requested data

Comment: @lzzy, based on my test, I find the following problems. First, I didn't see the addresses and address types table in your database. Second, most of the code you provided is not related to your question, please remove them. Third, I think you need to clarify your needs and logic so that others will understand your problem more clearly.

Comment: @JackJJun-MSFT: I removed the code that's not needed.
the tables are tbl_Relaties (dutch for "relations")
and tbl_types.

the form "formMakeRelationType" has code that updates the tbl_type table and it works and updates the listbox with relation types in this form.
Since relations can be multiple types at the samen time, but not every address "needs" certain types of info, if i don't select the types in listbox, the groupboxes with that irrelevant info should not be shown in order not to show too much data.
My idea was to do a select case code that shows the groupbox based on choices.

Comment: @lzzy, is any update?

Answer (score 1):

I found it...
based on an article in stackoverflow: [How to show hidden text boxes when items are selected in a combo box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23750879/how-to-show-hidden-text-boxes-when-items-are-selected-in-a-combo-box)

If someone knows how to make this piece of code "easier to handle" or "more compact" i'm very open to ideas.
Also: i can only select one , the rest of the groupboxes dissappear , so it needs some finetuning but i'm 90% there!

```
Private Sub lboxRelatieTypes_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lboxRelatieTypes.SelectedIndexChanged
        If lboxRelatieTypes.Text.Trim.Contains("Patiënt") = True Then
            Me.grpBasisData.Visible = True
            Me.grpDataBI.Visible = False
            Me.grpFoto_Nota.Visible = True
            Me.grpHuisartsData.Visible = False
            Me.grpPartijData.Visible = False
            Me.grpVerwijzerdata.Visible = False
        ElseIf lboxRelatieTypes.Text.Trim.Contains("Verwijzer") = True Then
            Me.grpBasisData.Visible = True
            Me.grpDataBI.Visible = False
            Me.grpFoto_Nota.Visible = True
            Me.grpHuisartsData.Visible = False
            Me.grpPartijData.Visible = False
            Me.grpVerwijzerdata.Visible = True
        ElseIf lboxRelatieTypes.Text.Trim.Contains("Betalende Instantie") = True Then
            Me.grpBasisData.Visible = True
            Me.grpDataBI.Visible = True
            Me.grpFoto_Nota.Visible = True
            Me.grpHuisartsData.Visible = False
            Me.grpPartijData.Visible = True
            Me.grpVerwijzerdata.Visible = False
        ElseIf lboxRelatieTypes.Text.Trim.Contains("Huisarts") = True Then
            Me.grpBasisData.Visible = True
            Me.grpDataBI.Visible = False
            Me.grpFoto_Nota.Visible = True
            Me.grpHuisartsData.Visible = True
            Me.grpPartijData.Visible = False
            Me.grpVerwijzerdata.Visible = False
        ElseIf lboxRelatieTypes.Text.Trim.Contains("Huisarts" & "Betalende Instantie") = True Then
            Me.grpBasisData.Visible = True
            Me.grpDataBI.Visible = True
            Me.grpFoto_Nota.Visible = True
            Me.grpHuisartsData.Visible = True
            Me.grpPartijData.Visible = False
            Me.grpVerwijzerdata.Visible = False
        End If

        'Dim curitem As String = lboxRelatieTypes.SelectedItems.ToString()
        'Dim con As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=F:\GoogleDrive\EINDWERK VBNET\PatientenDatabase.accdb")
        'con.Open()
        'Dim sql As String = String.Format("select * from tbl_Relaties where Rel_Type='{0}'", curitem)
        'Dim command As New OleDbCommand(sql, con)
        'Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
        'If curitem.Contains "Huisarts" Then
        ' End If
        'con.Close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I make a code example, which show the textbox in the groupbox based on the listbox.

Form_Load event:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim con As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:\PatientenDatabase.mdb")
        con.Open()
        Dim sql As String = "select Type_Naam from tbl_type"
        Dim command As New OleDbCommand(sql, con)
        Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
        While reader.Read()
            ListBox1.Items.Add(reader.GetString(0))
        End While

        con.Close()
    End Sub
```

Listboxindexchanged event:

```
Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
        Dim curItem As String = ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()
        Dim con As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:\PatientenDatabase.mdb")
        con.Open()
        Dim sql As String = String.Format("select * from tbl_Relaties where Rel_Type='{0}'", curItem)
        Dim command As New OleDbCommand(sql, con)
        Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()

        If reader.HasRows Then
            While reader.Read()
                txtID.Text = reader.GetValue(0).ToString()
                txtType.Text = reader.GetValue(1).ToString()
                txtName.Text = reader.GetValue(2).ToString()
                txtVoo.Text = reader.GetValue(3).ToString()
                txtAdress.Text = reader.GetValue(4).ToString()
            End While
        Else
            txtID.Text = String.Empty
            txtType.Text = String.Empty
            txtName.Text = String.Empty
            txtVoo.Text = String.Empty
            txtAdress.Text = String.Empty
        End If
        con.Close()
    End Sub
```

Final result:

[image]

Besides, I only make a few column code and you can follow the above code to complete the rest of the code.

Comment: J Jun: your example works fine , but it's not the problem ;-).
A relation in my database can be "many types".
a doctor can also be a forwarder, a paying instancy can also be a doctor and a forwarder,
multiple combo's are possible. So the listbox is "multiselect".
Every type has it's own extra groupbox with specific extra info.
So if i select "patient" , the groupbox 1 and 3 must become visible,
if it's also a paying instance, groupbox 4 must also become visible.
and so on.
Since the form is a "add new relation" form, no data needs to go into the textboxes, only appear when needed

Comment: like so: https://imgur.com/vlQ5BwN 
as soon as i click the groupboxes that are needed should appear in order to fill in the necessary data.
the groupboxes are set to "not visible"  and be set to "visible" when types are added.
i'm trying with "for each" and "select case" but i can't find the proper syntax

Comment: @lzzy, the gif you provided is not clear, can you give me a new screen to tell me what do you want to do.

Comment: J Jun :the screen looks like that (https://imgur.com/6qWO7LZ) , so when i want to add a relation type "patient" that's also a "paying instance" I select those in the left listbox.
the groupboxes that respond to that types should appear when selected.
my video to gif makes it too small i know , but it shows what's needed

Comment: @lzzy, do you mean that you can show the correct groupboxes based on the relationship in the database? If so, please tell me the specific relation.

Comment: That's the thing , i can't show them. They're all there, just set to invisible.
the code i need is something like "if this is selected, make this groupbox visible